# Make app fullscreen in service not activity

Tags: java, android

How can i make application full screen in Service? (No activity)

```
this.view = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.lockscreen, (ViewGroup)null);
this.windowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService("window");
final WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManagerLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
windowManagerLayoutParams.type = 2002;
windowManagerLayoutParams.format = 1;
windowManagerLayoutParams.height = -1;
windowManagerLayoutParams.width = -1;
windowManager.addView(this.view, (WindowManager.LayoutParams)windowManagerLayoutParams);
```

Comment: The question which duplicate it is marked is not available!

Comment: Yes, the question which this one has been marked as a duplicate of is deleted, you need 10k rep to view it. @CommonsWare

Comment: @XaverKapeller: It was not deleted at the time I marked it as a duplicate, though they must have been close time-wise.

Comment: Out of interest, what would be the purpose of this? Creating a full screen non-activity would just leave a blank screen, no? What would you have to show?